# PyPi page of package showing pip install instead of pip3 install

Tags: pip, pypi

I recently uploaded a python3 package on the main PyPi. In the description, I have explicitly mentioned that in order to install the package, the user needs to type "pip3 install pkg_name". In the languages also Python3 is mentioned. However, on the top, below the package name, the page shows "pip install pkg_name". Shouldn't it be displaying "pip3 install pkg_name"? I guess a few years earlier it used to show "pip3 install pkg_name" on the top of the page, but I am not sure. Could anyone please clarify?
I am attaching example screenshots.   [Top part of the PyPi page of the python package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjse1.png)
[Installation description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZiLD.png)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same. If you look at the pip3 file in the bin folder it calls the `main` function from the pip module.

`pip3 install package_name` runs pip3 file in the bin folder:

```py
    # bin/pip3 
    # or bin/pip if using pip install package_name
    
    import re
    import sys
    
    from pip import main
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(main())
```

`python3 -m pip install package_name` runs the `__init__.py` file of the [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/__init__.py) module.

```py
    # pip/__init__.py
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        sys.exit(main())
```

Both of them run the same `main()` function

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. One small doubt- did PyPi page ever show "pip3 install pkg_name" at the top for python3 packages at some point of time in the past, or has it always been "pip install pkg_name" ?

Comment: It has always been ```pip install <package name>```, as far as I know.

Comment: Glad to help you. If the answer is the correct one, please mark it.

Comment: Yes, I clicked on the button showing "The answer is useful". But it is displaying this message-"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."